# App crashing in UItableView cell for row

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I am trying to create a sample app with tableView and populating  NSArray on that  tableview . it crashes everytime i scroll when i declare array using

```
NSArray *listItems = @[];
```

when i change back the array declaration to

```
NSArray * listItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",

        @"b",
        @"c",
        @"d",
        @"e",
        @"f",
        @"g",
        @"h",
        @"i",
        @"j",
        @"k",
        @"l",
        @"m",
        @"n",
        @"o",
        @"p",
        @"q",
        @"r",
        @"s",
        @"t",
        @"u",
        @"v",
        @"w",
        @"x",
        @"y",
        @"z",
        @"1",
        @"2",
        @"3 ",
        @"4 ",
        @"5 ",
        @"6 ",
        @"7 ",
        @"8 ",
        @"9",
        @"0",
        @"12",nil]retain];
```

it works fine ! . what is the difference between both ? iam using non-ARC environment . Here is my code

```
#import "MyPopOverView.h"



@implementation MyPopOverView

@synthesize tableListiTems;

@synthesize lists;

@synthesize listDict;






/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableListiTems.delegate = self;
    tableListiTems.dataSource = self;

    listDict = @{
                 @"a":
                 @"b", // Register,
                 @"c":
                 @"d",
                 @"e":
                 @"f",
                 @"g":
                 @"h",
                 @"i":
                 @"j",
                 @"k":
                 @"l ",
                 @"m":
                 @"n"};



    lists = @[
        @"a",
        @"b",
        @"c",
        @"d",
        @"e",
        @"f",
        @"g",
        @"h",
        @"i",
        @"j",
        @"k",
        @"l",
        @"m",
        @"n",
        @"o",
        @"p",
        @"q",
        @"r",
        @"s",
        @"t",
        @"u",
        @"v",
        @"w",
        @"x",
        @"y",
        @"z",
        @"1",
        @"2",
        @"3 ",
        @"4 ",
        @"5 ",
        @"6 ",
        @"7 ",
        @"8 ",
        @"9",
        @"0",
        @"12",
];


}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return [lists count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: what is your property of lists array and when it is crash?

Comment: What is the crash?  When you use the alternate array declaration do you still `retain` it?  Why aren't you using ARC? Is it old code or are you just a fan of memory leaks :)?

Comment: i mentioned in the quesion it crashes only when i scrolls the tableview .

Comment: property is (nonatomic,retain)

Comment: If it's a property, you should set it using `self.lists = ...` so it gets retained.  This has been covered in Apple documentation and in hundreds of SO answers.

Comment: That is when it crashes,  but not the crash message. I presume it is an access exception because you aren't retaining the array

Comment: @Anna but why its not crashing on alloc init ?

Comment: Because you put the `retain` there.  Using `self.xxx` automatically does that for you because the @synthesize auto-generates that code (essentially).  When you do `lists = @[xxx];` you get an auto-released object which disappears when the method ends and `lists` no longer points to valid memory.

Comment: goto product->scheme->editscheme  and there enable objective-c enable zombie object....then it will print a crash report.and there you can understand the problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: @Anna please post it as a answer thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *listItems = @[];
```

Returns autotoreleased object: `[NSArray array]`.
Please add retain:

```
NSArray *listItems = @[].retain;
```

P.S.: Do not forget to release it.